# Setting a timer to enable/disable a trigger on Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, timer, triggers, click

I currently have a trigger which updates with a new value every 15 minutes. Unfortunately it updates continuously.

I'd like it to stop between 08:00 and 16:00 for example.

Is there a way to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes there is a way!**

What you can do in this situation is to:

#### Method 1

1. Create a new trigger which will fire at **08:00** to delete the previous trigger.

To delete a trigger, you can use something similar to this, according to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_programmatically):

```
function deleteTrigger(triggerId) {
  var allTriggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  for (var i = 0; i < allTriggers.length; i++) {
    if (allTriggers[i].getUniqueId() === triggerId) {
      ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(allTriggers[i]);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

2. Create a new trigger which will fire at **16:00** to create the new trigger which runs every 15 minutes.

#### Method 2

Customize your trigger in such a way that it triggers **only** for the specific action you need/want.

#### Reference

- [Apps Script Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable).